# Notation of: a · b = 0 if a, b are orthogonal.

Tags: notation, orthogonality

I would like to express the concept **a · b = 0 if a, b are orthogonal**  in set theory notation (predicate calculus ?).

The nearest I have managed so far is:

If $a\cdot b=0 \space \space\forall\ a,b\subseteq S, \space$then $a,b$ are orthogonal (where $S$ is some previously defined set). This looks horrible and is longer than the original sentence in words.

Can someone help me to make it look better and to correctly represent the original phrase?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Do yo want to define "orthogonal" this way or make a statement about a pre-existing orthogonality predicate? This seems to be more about predicate calculus than set theory

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen -  make a statement about a pre-existing orthogonality

Comment: As you have verified, there is no benefit in orthogonal(a,b) vs "a, b are orthogonal "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \forall a,b \in S \colon a \cdot b = 0 \iff a \perp b $$

Although you might want to use the notation $\langle a,b \rangle$ instead of $a \cdot b$

Comment: Thanks that is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for.   I'll just mention that you used bidirectional implication. In the original wording I specified **if** rather than **iff**  - I do  understand that under some definitions of orthogonality that your statement is true but in this case I wasn't specifying that.

Comment: Sure, but this is *the* definition of orthogonality, I think pretty much universally so, meaning that the implication does go either way